# How to store a map using :dets in Elixir?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir, dets

I want to be able to store a map using :dets

Currently, that is the solution I am trying to implement:

```
# a list of strings
topics = GenServer.call(MessageBroker.TopicsProvider, {:get_topics})

# a map with each element of the list as key and an empty list as value
topics_map =
  topics
  |> Enum.chunk_every(1)
  |> Map.new(fn [k] -> {k, []} end)

{:ok, table} = :dets.open_file(:messages, type: :set)

# trying to store the map
:dets.insert(table, [topics_map])

:dets.close(table)
```

However, I get

```
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
    ** (ArgumentError) argument error
        (stdlib 3.12) dets.erl:1259: :dets.insert(:messages, [%{"tweet" => [], "user" => []}])
```

How is it possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chen Yu's solution is good, but before getting it I already found another solution.
Basically, you can just add the map to a tuple

```
:dets.insert(table, {:map, topics_map})
```

Then, you can get this map by using

```
:dets.lookup(table, :map)
```

Comment: *dets: This module provides a term storage on file. The stored terms...are tuples such that one element is defined to be the key.*  See : https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html

Answer (score 1):

I have tested by erlang. You should convert the map to list first.

[Following from dets:insert_new() doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dets.html#insert_new-2)

```
insert_new(Name, Objects) -> boolean() | {error, Reason}
Types
Name = tab_name()
Objects = object() | [object()] 
Reason = term()
Inserts one or more objects into table Name. If there already exists some object with a key matching the key of any of the specified objects, the table is not updated and false is returned. Otherwise the objects are inserted and true returned.
```

test code

```
dets:open_file(dets_a,[{file,"/tmp/aab"}]).
Map = #{a => 2, b => 3, c=> 4, "a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 4}.
List_a = maps:to_list(Map). %% <----- this line
dets:insert(dets_a,List_a).
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your intent, you want to store `users` and `tweets` under separate keys. For that, you need to construct a keyword list, not a map, in the first place.

```elixir
topics = for topic <- topics, do: {topic, []}
# or topics = Enum.map(topics, &{&1, []})
# or topics = Enum.map(topics, fn topic -> {topic, []} end)
```

then you might use this keyword list to create `dets`.

```elixir
{:ok, table} = :dets.open_file(:messages, type: :set)
:dets.insert(table, topics)
:dets.close(table)
```